# How to show a "no data" message in AngulrJS ngTable plugin tables when the response data array is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, html-table, ngtable

I want to display a no data message in my ngTable table when the response data array is empty.

So far I have this

```
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
            <td data-title="'name'" filter="{name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">{{row.name}}</td>
            <td data-title="'lastName'" filter="{lastName: 'text'}" sortable="'lastName'">{{row.lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-show="$data.length == 0">
                There's no data
            </td>
        </tr>
```

but what this does is that it shows that message in the first column, I want that message background to take all the columns, I mean I don't want to repeat the message in all columns, I want to show the message in the center of the first row of the table; Or at the beginning of the first column but not limit this message to the first column boundaries.

Another example would be like the bootstrap zebra stripes table, I want the message to take a full stripe color, but the messages can't be limited to a specific column it should display in the entire row.

Is there a option in the ngTble plgun for this, like in the jQuery data-tables plugin message that says "no data available" when the table is empty

Answer (score 5):

You should use colspan to keep it consistant.

```
<td colspan="2" ng-show="$data.length == 0"> 
    There's no data 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, just remove this `<td></td>` from the table..

```
<td ng-show="$data.length == 0">
                There's no data
</td>
```

And put this..

```
<div ng-if="$data.length == 0">Oops, no record found!</div>
```

and in your table put a condition...

```
<table ng-if="$data.length > 0"></table>
```